# ArrayList toString works in println but not in textfield

Tags: java

```
table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {


                String val1 = table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 1).toString();
                String val2 = table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 2).toString();
                String val3 = table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 3).toString();
                String val4 = table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 4).toString();

                ArrayList<String> row = new ArrayList<String>();

                row.add(val1);
                row.add(val2);
                row.add(val3);
                row.add(val4);

                //new KundeTab().kundeAuswahl.setText(row.toString());

                //EDIT: this was the solution

                    String listString = "";
                    for (String s : row) {
                    listString += s + " ";
                    }
                    KundeTab.kundeAuswahl.setText(listString);

                // output works
                System.out.println(row.toString());

            }
        });
```

why do i get an output in sysout but not in my textfield? 
what am i doing wrong?

thanks for your help!

**EDIT:
new KundeTab() refers to another class. In this class is a JTextField kundeAuswahl.**

Comment: I believe removing `kundeAuswahl.setText(row.toString());` should do the trick.

Comment: I have a feeling you're not setting the text on the right box.

Comment: kundeAuswahl is a JTextField in my class KundeTab. That's where i want to print the String.

Comment: But why do you want to do it in a new `KundeTab` and not an already-existing `KundeTab`?

Comment: I would like to! But i how can i access the textfield without creating a new one?

Comment: Why did you change it to `new Class().jTextField.setText(row.toString());`?

Comment: i edited the code to a working one! Thanks to Jack Kirby!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's a list, you need to specify which element to print using `row.get(index);`

If you want to print the whole list, properly convert it to a regular string first, then add it to your text field:

```
String listString = "";

for (String s : row)
{
    listString += s + "\t";
}   

  new KundeTab().kundeAuswahl.setText(listString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything with the new `KundeTab`. I don't know what one of those is, but try something like:

```
KundeTab() tab = new KundeTab();
tab.kundeAuswahl.setText(row.toString());
mainPanel.add(tab); // or whatever you need to do to make it display
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance of `KundeTab`, then setting the text on the new textbox.  This textbox then gets garbage collected.

Now, I assume that this method is in the `KundeTab` class.  In this case, you should simply call:

```
KundeTab.this.kundeAuswahl.setText(row.toString());
```